# How to generate password manually hashed like passport-local-mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local, seeding, password-hash

I created a user register api and I use [passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose) library, and now, I'm creating a seeder so I have to store the password on my database manually, How can I do that?

Here's my api code for registration

```
api.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body
    const account = await Account.findOne({ email })
    if (account) {
        res.status(409).send('Email already exist!')
        return
    } 
    await Account.register(new Account(
        { 
            username: username ,
            email: email,
            role: 'player'
        }),
        req.body.password
    );

    passport.authenticate(
        'local', {
            session: false
        }
    )

    res.status(201).send('Account Created!')
});
```

Note: that `Account` was a model